# CrateDB - setting custom column as primary key automatically sets it as "_id" column

Tags: primary-key, cratedb

Assume I create table `users` with columns (`firstname, lastname, email, address etc.`). `CrateDB` automatically adds `_id` column, whose values are some kind of weird strings. 
If I set `email` column as PRIMARY KEY on table creation, then `_id` column becomes filled with values from `email` column, i.e. ID's of records become emails. Is there any way to retain "weird strings" as ID's in `_id` column and leave `email` column as PRIMARY KEY?

P.S. `email` column must be PRIMARY KEY, as I want to ensure unique emails in that column.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no way to change that.
When there is exactly one primary key column the value of the primary column is used. When you have two and more it is base64 encoded.

Why do you need to uuid string?